# How to intercept exceptions raised in .designer.cs

Tags: c#, exception

I have a component that any time someone closes the application, it raises an exception in it's Dispose method. It's only when they leave the application and the exception is not even showed to them. But it pollutes my error log.

Is there a simple way to intercept that precise error at that precise line in an auto-generated file?

Thank you!
Mathieu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bug in your control's `Dispose()` method, which is being called from the auto-generated `Dispose` method.

You should set Visual Studio to break on all exceptions (click Debug, Exceptions) and find and fix the bug.

Comment: Thanx, I see it was not pointing me the error at the right place for that reason.

Comment: It's funny because it's on the line base.Dispose(disposing); and not components.Dispose();